# Wix Toolset can't grant permission to user in install directory

Tags: wix, wix3.5

My app writes log using log4net in the appinstalldirectory\log directory but the app is not able to create log directory and create file. It was because on security tab current login user which is local admin in windows 10 was not added as list of user who has full access to that folder.

Thus in wix installer I have created a component as below

```
<CreateFolder>
    <util:PermissionEx
        GenericAll="yes"
        CreateFile="yes"
        User="[UserSID]"
        Domain="[%USERDOMAIN]"/>
    
    <!--<Permission 
        GenericAll="yes"
        CreateFile="yes"
        User="[UserSID]" 
        Domain="[%USERDOMAIN]"/>-->
</CreateFolder>
```

With ***PermissionEx*** the installer doesn't complete and show message as below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiCbk.png
[image: Image when PermissionEx is used]

But when  is used I get error as below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXNpO.png
[image: Image when Permission is used]

When I check the usersid in command I can see that usersid
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDVpC.png
[image: Image of available user accounts]

Could some one please point me what is wrong or what should I do? I don't want to keep modifying every system and grant current user full access so that my app can write log.

Answer (score 0):

Use the username, not the SID

```
<CreateFolder>
    <util:PermissionEx
        GenericAll="yes"
        CreateFile="yes"
        User="[LogonUser]"
        Domain="[%USERDOMAIN]"/>
</CreateFolder>
```